# How would I make it so that python checks a specific value in my array?

Tags: python

If I were to write:

```
c = str.split(input())
```

How do I have python check, for example, the first value in the array 'c'

I tried to do:

```
if c[0] is 0:
   #dosomething
```

But it doesn't seem to work.
Is there any way I could do this?

Comment: It's probably because ``c[0]`` is a character but ``0`` is an int. ``if c[0] is '0'`` should work.

Comment: uhm.. have you tried with `c = input().split()`

Comment: What do you mean by check it? do you want to return it or see if it fits certain criteria; if so please specify what criteria.

Answer (score 3):

First, you're checking equality with `is`, which is for identity. Use `==`.

Second, you're comparing `c[0]` to a number, while it's a single-character string. Compare it to a string of `'0'`.

```
if c[0] == '0':
    pass
```

You could also cast `c[0]` to a number instead:

```
if int(c[0]) == 0:
    pass
```

Comment: @George: Standard CPython may have a pool of length-1 strings representing latin-1 characters, and a pool of int objects for small integers, but these are implementation details you cannot rely on. Simply stating that `is` "works" for these comparisons without any mention of the caveats will just confuse people.

Comment: Thanks that helped a lot!